# Applying Groovy RegEx with Conditional Matching

Tags: regex, groovy

Using Groovy and regular expression(s) how can I convert this:

```
String shopping = "SHOPPING LIST(TOMATOES, TEA, LENTIL SOUP: packets=2) for Saturday"
```

to print out

```
Shopping for Saturday
TOMATOES
TEA
LENTIL SOUP (2 packets)
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I can get the list printed out but the conditional 'packets' are causing grief with String argRegex = /.*(\w*(:? packets.*)\))/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a regex guru, so i couldn't find a regex to do the conversion in just on [`replaceAll`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.util.regex.Pattern,%20java.lang.String%29) step (i think it should be possible to do it that way). This works though:

```
def shopping = "SHOPPING LIST(TOMATOES, TEA, LENTIL SOUP: packets=2) for Saturday"

def (list, day) = (shopping =~ /SHOPPING LIST\((.*)\) for (\w+)/)[0][1,2]
println "Shopping for $day\n" + 
        list.replaceAll(/: packets=(\d+)/, ' ($1 packets)')
            .replaceAll(', ', '\n')
```

First it captures the strings `"TOMATOES, TEA: packets=50, LENTIL SOUP: packets=2"` and `"Saturday"` into the variables `list` and `day` respectively. Then it processes the `list` string to convert it in the desired output replacing the `"packets="` occurrences and splitting the list by commas (`.replaceAll(', ', '\n')` is equivalent to `.split(', ').join('\n')`).

One thing to notice is that if the `shopping` string does not match the first regex, it will throw an exception for trying to access the first match (`[0]`). You can avoid that by doing:

```
(shopping =~ /SHOPPING LIST\((.*)\) for (\w+)/).each { match, list, day ->
    println "Shopping for $day\n" + 
            list.replaceAll(/: packets=(\d+)/, ' ($1 packets)')
                .replaceAll(', ', '\n')
}
```

Which won't print anything if the first regex doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks, I like the shorthand use of the first group arg for the packets

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the String `find` method for these kinds of cases, I think it's clearer than the `=~` syntax:

```
String shopping = "SHOPPING LIST(TOMATOES, TEA, LENTIL SOUP: packets=2) for Saturday"

def expected = """Shopping for Saturday
TOMATOES
TEA
LENTIL SOUP (2 packets)"""


def regex = /SHOPPING LIST\((.*)\) for (.+)/

assert expected == shopping.find(regex) { full, items, day ->
    List<String> formattedItems = items.split(", ").collect { it.replaceAll(/: packets=(\d+)/, ' ($1 packets)') }
    "Shopping for $day\n" + formattedItems.join("\n")
}
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about the `String#find` method. I agree that in this case it's clearer than using `=~` :)